# Begründung für das Komma bei als mit Konjunktiv

Tags: subjunctive, subordinate-clause, comma

Wenn »als« einen Nebensatz einleitet, wird es (und dieser) mit Komma abgetrennt, z. B.:

> Er ist schon älter, als sie bei dem Unfall war.

Nebensätze erkenne man daran, dass das finite Verb am Ende stehe, so noch hilfreich die Duden-Rechtschreibprüfung.  Hier passt also alles, hier ist keine Frage.

Ich frage mich aber, was bei folgendem Satz mit Konjunktiv das Komma rechtfertigt:

> Er sah aus, als hätte er Angst.

Ich finde kein finites Verb (»hätte«) am Ende, bin deshalb am Zweifeln, ob »als hätte er Angst« ein Nebensatz ist.  Vielleicht ist es eine spezielle Form des Nebensatzes?  Mit den typischen Nebensatz einleitenden Konjunktionen wie »weil« kann ich diese Wortgruppe jedenfalls nicht kombinieren.  Oder gibt es noch andere Regeln, die vorschreiben, dass das »als« ein Komma erhält?

Kann mich jemand erhellen und mir erklären, wie das Komma vor dem »als« gerechtfertigt ist?  Idealerweise unter Bezugnahme auf die aktuellen Rechtschreibregeln, wie sie z.B. unter https://www.korrekturen.de/regelwerk/pdf/Regeln_2018.pdf zu finden sind, aber auch ohne diese Referenz wäre ich für eine Antwort dankbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Die Phrase "als hätte er Angst" hat ein Subjekt, Prädikat, Objekt und "als" als Konjunktion, da sehe ich genügend Gründe, das auch einen Nebensatz zu nennen. Die Wortreihenfolge ist mit diesem speziellen Vergleichs-"als" einfach nur anders als bei anderen Konjunktionen.

"Als" wird in den beiden Beispielsätzen etwas unterschiedlich gebraucht, deshalb die verschiedene Wortreihenfolge. Im zweiten Beispiel werden durch das "als" die beiden Sätze "Er sah aus" und "er hatte Angst" als Ganze zueinander in Beziehung gesetzt. Im ersten Beispiel steht "als" dagegen mit dem Komparativ "älter", das heißt, es werden nicht zwei ganze Vorgänge, sondern nur die Eigenschaft aus dem Komparativ, das Alter, verglichen.

Siehe z.B. Bedeutung 1 vs Bedeutung 2 hier: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/als_in_Vergleichen

EDIT:
In der Duden-Grammatik (8.Auflage, Abschnitt 1671) ist von solchen Konstruktionen als "Verberstnebensatz" die Rede. Erstes Beispiel dort: "Otto keuchte, als wäre er dreihundert Meter gerannt."

Comment: Das ist alles offensichtlich richtig und deswegen bringt es mich nicht weiter.  Die Frage ist:  Reicht es, dass eine Wortgruppe Subjekt und Prädikat hat, um sie »Nebensatz« zu nennen?  Kann man das mit irgendetwas belegen?  Möglichst mit mehr als einfach nur der persönlichen Meinung?  (D. h. Duden oder so.)

Comment: In der Duden Grammatik ist das definiert, ja. Die verschiedenen Definitionen eines Satzes bzw. Nebensatzes, die da drinstehen, sind zu komplex, um sie hier zu referieren, die Duden-Grammatik kennt allein drei Definition von "Satz", aber wenn das Gebilde ein eigenes Subjekt und Prädikat hat, ist es danach auf jeden Fall ein Teilsatz, und ein untergeordneter Teilsatz ist ein Nebensatz.

Comment: In dem Duden-Link, den ich in der Antwort gepostet habe, steht das Beispiel: "Er sah, als habe er nichts gehört, aus dem Fenster", das entspricht von der Struktur schon sehr weitgehend deinem zweiten Beispiel.

Comment: Wenn du in der Duden-Grammatik suchst: Abschnitt 1671. "Nebensätze mit als, in denen das Verb unmittelbar auf die Subjunktion folgt (Verberstnebensatz)" Erstes Beispiel dort: "Otto keuchte, als wäre er dreihundert Meter gerannt."

Answer (score 1):

**Nebensätze**: Deine Annahme, (bzw. die Aussage, man erkenne  Nebensätze daran [sic!], dass das finite Verb am Schluss stehe), stimmt nur *meistens*. Es gibt Ausnahmen, du hast eine davon in deinem Beispiel - Mit der Konjunktion *als* (nicht *als ob*) eingeleitete Nebensätze konnen das Verb an V2-Position (direkt nach dem "als") haben. Ein anderes Beispiel sind uneingeleitete Nebensätze (ohne Konjunktion), wie z.B "Er sagte, er käme heute nicht".

Einigen wir uns darauf, dass es sich bei "als hätte er Angst" um einen Nebensatz handelt - bis auf die ausnahmsweise fehlende Verbletztstellung hat er alles, was einen Nebensatz ausmacht:

- es ist ein Teilsatz
- er kann nicht alleine stehen
- er hängt vom Hauptsatz ab
- er wird durch eine unterordnende Konjunktion ("als") eingeleitet

Handelt es sich also um einen Nebensatz, gilt ganz pauschal §74:

> *Nebensätze grenzt man mit Komma ab; sind sie eingeschoben, so schließt man sie mit paarigem Komma ein*

Comment: Oder ganz einfach: Ein Nebensatz ist ein Satz mit Subjekt und darauf gebeugtes Verb, und als solcher muss er durch Beistrich(e) getrennt werden.

Comment: @rexkogitans Autsch. Das trifft auch auf einen Hauptsatz zu.

Comment: Es war nicht wirklich meine Annahme, dass Nebensätze immer das Verb am Ende haben; es war nur die einzige Aussage (von einer offiziellen Quelle wie dem Duden), die ich dazu habe. Gibt es eine vergleichbare Quelle, die besagt, dass die mit einem Konjunktiv eingeleiteten Sätze ebenfalls Nebensätze sind bzw. noch allgemeiner, wann eine Wortgruppe »Nebensatz« genannt wird?  Mir ist nicht wohl bei der Situation, dass wir einfach mal annehmen, dass die Wortgruppe ein Nebensatz ist.  Reichen Subjekt und Prädikat, um eine Wortgruppe Nebensatz zu nennen?  Mir ging es mehr um eine offizielle Begründung.

Comment: @Toto natürlich, "Ich gehe, du bleibst." wären zwei Hauptsätze, auch da muss ein Beistrich dazwischen sein.

Comment: @Alfe Die vier oben genannten Kriterien sind die, die gemeinhin als Definition für einen Nebensatz verwendet werden.